# Nested view pager (VERY STUCK)

Tags: android, android-layout, android-viewpager, android-recyclerview

I am using a view pager in a recycler view cell, which is swiped to reveal a checkmark image. Outside of this, the recycler view is contained in a fragment which is located inside of another viewpager. What I want to accomplish is, after the cell's viewpager finishes, it begins to drag the view pager containing the fragment. I have been working on this for two days and have not reached any solution. It works fine if I lift my finger between swiping the view pager in the cell and then swiping the screen again to swipe the fragment's view pager. However, I want this swipe to be possible without having to lift a finger off the screen. A good model of this is snapchat's swipe to message views. Any help would seriously be appreciated. i do not know what to do. I can provide code, but it's fairly complicated and messy.

The images below are the current app I am trying to execute this behavior in. They are for testing purposes of course. Image 1) is before nothing is swiped. Image 2) is after the cell's view pager has been swiped, and Image 3) is after the fragment's view pager has been swiped. What I want is for there to be no need to touch the screen twice in between images two and three.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: I think you need to rethink your UI choices.

Comment: This is in no way helpful. @cricket_007

Answer (score 0):

best solution is to find a view that does the swipe effect without a pager
cause this is a lot of nested views
I've used one before that has done the job

check this library I used it to implement a row with a swipe to show call button and was inside a tabbed activity didn't have any issues
https://github.com/daimajia/AndroidSwipeLayout

goodluck

Comment: Thanks! Yeah, I considered this, but I am trying to use as few libraries as possible, mainly for reliability reasons. I will give it a try, though.

Comment: I know but this is a small lib and sometimes you kinda have to .
but nested scroll of any type is awful and hard to control.
If you have time you can rethink how to do it or check implementations for it

Comment: Yeah, I just saw that they don't support recycler view, unfortunately.

Comment: yes I used it with a listview I just checked.
but you can use swipe layout as a view in the row not the adapter.

Comment: my problem is i want my outer-layer view pager to swipe after the swipeview has finished. do you know if this will work?

Comment: it has a listener that handle all states including onClose
but I didn't use it personally
sorry I can't help you more 
give it a quick try even with a small sample